# How can I get image from api rest using reactjs

Tags: reactjs, image

I am developping an application which is based on Images, first I save data (title, description, images...) on mySql database using API rest and spring boot in the backend, I need to show and display what I saved I use react as a frondend on other hand I use `"react-images-upload"`to upload, preview and handle images.
Until this instance this what I did in my code react:

**item.js:**

```
import React, { useState, Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import ItemList from './itemList'

class Item extends Component{

        constructor(props){
            super(props);
            this.state={
                items:[],
                ...//others
            }
        }

        componentDidMount(){
            this.getItems();
          }

        getItems(){
            const url="MY_API_URL";
            axios({
                method: 'get',
                dataType: 'json',
                url: 'URL',
                headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
    }).then((resp:AxiosResponse<T>)=>{
                console.log(resp.data);//on my browser's console I get:[object Object],[object Object]
                console.log(resp.data.photo);//on my browser's console I get:undefined
                this.setState({
                    items:resp.data
                });

            }).catch((err=>{
                console.log(err);
            }));

        }

    render(){
        return (
            <div className=""> 
                <div className="row"> 
                {      
                    this.state.items.map(item=>
                        <ItemList item={item}/>
                    )                      
                }
                </div> 
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default Item;
```

**itemList.js:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class itemList extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
           <div className="col-md-4" key={this.props.item.id}>
                <div className="card">
                 <div className="card-header">{this.props.item.title}</div> 
                 <div className="card-body">
                   {this.props.item.photo.map(photo=><img src={photo} />=)}{/* I can't display the image! */}
                 </div>
                </div>
          </div>
        );
    }
}    
export default itemList;
```

I get this result:

[image]

And this is how images stored on my database:
[image]

Please can someone help me to dispolay images from database

Edit1: the response from api request look like :

```
        "id": 1,
        "title": "test with pic 3",
        "description": "descp how are you",
        "photo": [
            "[object File]",
            "[object File]",
            "[object File]"
        ]
```

Comment: How does your response from api request look like

Comment: "id": 1,
        "title": "test with pic 3",
        "description": "descp how are you",
        "photo": [
            "[object File]",
            "[object File]",
            "[object File]"
        ]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that it is a `Blob` you are sending. Looking at the picture it looks like MySQL. You have to transform it on your server-side code because only `MySQL` knows what a `Blob` is.. React doesn't.

Solution 1: Base64, you can transform the blob into a base64 string on your server, and then you can actually just keep all of your code. Then you will just have a very long string, which is a string representation of your image. A regular jsx `<img src={} />` tag will be sufficient.

Solution 2: Serving image statically, you can also make your server serve the images in a static fashion, similarly, if you go to a website, and see an image, you can see some URL, where the image is stored. You can do this with most server-side technologies or on the cloud. Then you can just pass the image URL to your React client, and it will work.

Let me know if you have any more questions.